# SAP finding and replacing a value

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

So I work in the vending industry, and SAP, there is a t-code that lists a specific material number in a specific line on the data table in SAP.  However for each location, this specific line, will be different, and the value of that material number will be different.

I have already recorded and output the script for me manual going in an clicking each line of the data and then replacing the value, but my hope is to automate this using an Excel file that another program outputs.  Does anyone know if this is possible??